# Difficulty with itertools.dropwhile

Tags: python, python-itertools

I'm trying to use `itertools.dropwhile` to only return elements from a generator that come after the third element, but I'm having a bit of trouble:

```
from itertools import dropwhile

    it = (i for i in range(10,20))
    a = dropwhile(enumerate < 3, it)   
    next(a)
    TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

The output I'm looking for is:

```
[14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Can anyone explain what is wrong with my code and provide a working solution? Thanks.

Comment: Isn't `13` also expected to appear in the output?

Comment: `(i for i in range(10,20))` is redundant. You can iterate over `range(10, 20)` as is.

Comment: Yes, `dropwhile` is comparing the value of the item.  Use `islice` to handle indices.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`itertools` provides a function that does exactly what you want and more. From [the Python Standard Library](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice),

> itertools.**`islice`**(*iterable*[, *start*], *stop*[, *step*])
>
> Make an iterator that returns selected elements from the iterable. If *start* is non-zero, then elements from the iterable are skipped until *start* is reached. Afterward, elements are returned consecutively unless *step* is set higher than one which results in items being skipped. If *stop* is `None`, then iteration continues until the iterator is exhausted, if at all; otherwise, it stops at the specified position.

```py
>>> import itertools
>>> it = (i for i in range(10, 20)) # it = xrange(10, 20)
>>> a = itertools.islice(it, 4, None)
>>> list(a)
[14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think to use `islice`. Definitely, the cleanest solution.

Comment: @turtle: `range(10,20)[4:]` or `range(14, 20)` is even better. Call `list(result)` to get a list on Python 3.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian `islice` is more portable because `xrange(10, 20)[4:]` is not supported in Python 2. I agree that, in Python 3 only, your `range(10, 20)[4:]` is better.

Comment: @DeokhwanKim: the OP's code is Python 2. `range(10, 20)[4:]` works on Python 2 (because `range` returns a list). `list(range(10, 20)[4:])` works on Python 3. But I see your point if you want the result to be an iterator, not a sequence.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian @turtle I get a little confused by J. F. Sebastian's last comment. My answer is based on speculation that the question is about how to get its sub-iterator from an iterator and that the `(i for i in range(10, 20))` part is just a mistake that crept in during making out a small code snippet. If the final goal is just getting its sub-`list` from `range()` in Python 2, both `dropwhile` and `islice` are overkill and list slicing is absoultely a way to go as J. F. Sebastian said.

Answer (score 3):

The `predicate` argument to `itertools.dropwhile` should be a function that accepts a single argument, `enumerate < 3` is just a statement.  On Python 2.x this will always evaluate to False because `"type" > "int"`, and on Python 3.x it will result in a `TypeError: unorderable types: type() < int()`.

Here is how you could change your code and still use `dropwhile`:

```
>>> it = (i for i in range(10, 20))
>>> a = dropwhile(lambda i_v: i_v[0] < 4, enumerate(it))
>>> list(a)
[(4, 14), (5, 15), (6, 16), (7, 17), (8, 18), (9, 19)]
```

Note that `enumerate` has to be called on the iterable so that we can create a lambda that uses the index to determine whether or not to drop the current value, but this means the result is a list of `(index, value)` tuples instead of just values.  I also changed the comparison to `< 4` since you wanted to start at `14`, which is the fourth element of `it`.

A better alternative is to use `itertools.islice` as in [Deokhwan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12081933/505154).

Answer (score 1):

Some of the other answers here are helpful, but they don't give exactly the results requested.  The accepted answer explains the useful `itertools.islice()`, but if using `itertools.dropwhile()` was a requirement, then it's not quite right.  Some other answers are unnecessarily complex.

A simple solution may be easier to find than expected.  For example:

```
list(dropwhile(lambda x: x < 14, xrange(10, 20)))
```

I wrapped this in `list()` since the specific result requested was `[14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]`.  That part can be removed to use `dropwhile()` as an iterator with `.next()`, etc.  Since this is an iterator, instead of `range()` I used `xrange()`, because that's more efficient with iterators.  `range()` would work, but maybe not as efficiently.

I'm not sure whether part of the goal was to use `enumerate()` as well.  Maybe it was, but in the example `enumerate` was used as a variable, not a function.  Enumeration isn't necessary to get the results requested, and it wasn't part of the question, so I assume it was used by mistake.

As others pointed out, the example in the question didn't need to use a comprehension to get all the items from the range.  This answer doesn't use it, either.  If we were to simplify the code even more, the simplest solution to get the results requested is:

```
range(14, 20)
```

But that doesn't include the goal of using `itertools.dropwhile()`.

Answer (score -1):

try that:

```
a = dropwhile(lambda x:x < 3, it)
```

argument must be callable.

Answer (score -1):

```
 it = (i for i in range(10,20))
```

This is kinda redundant, why not simply use `range(10,20)` (or `xrange`)?

Your code breaks because `dropwhile` expects a function as its argument and you're providing a boolean value (made by comparing function `enumerate` against the number 3, which is just a little bit strange!)

A solution using enumerate could look like:

```
a = dropwhile(lambda (i,val): i<3), enumerate(seq))
```

but then `a` is still a list of enumerated pairs (index, value).

A more efficient way could perhaps look like this:

```
class Counter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.n = 0

    def __call__(self):
        current = self.n
        self.n += 1
        return current
```

(see it in action [here](http://ideone.com/hOyHJ), it's quite simple)

then you can use it like:

```
c = Counter()
a = dropwhile(lambda elem: c() < 3, seq)
```

which allows you to achieve your goal using `dropwhile`. Your counter instance is called once for each element in seq and gives the next number every time.

---

That said, you're much better off using `itertools.islice`:

```
import itertools
a = itertools.islice(range(10, 20), 3, None)
```

`islice` allows you to do slices much like list slices (like `myList[3:]` in this case, from element #3 to the end), but can take any sequence as its argument.

Comment: Two arguments to the function in dropwhile won't work, in Python 2.x you could use `lambda (i,val): ...` but that is a SyntaxError on Python 3.x.  I like the `Counter` approach, but would probably use [`itertools.count()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) instead of creating a new class.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the lack of parens, and yes, I kind of miss tuple unpacking in py3. Thanks for mentioning `count` too, even though I only suggested the Counter class for illustration as `islice` is the actual solution here.